# Migrate swift 3 code to swift 5 using Xcode Version 11.3.1

Tags: swift3, swift5, xcode11.3

I have an old code developed at Xcode 8 with swift3,
Now with Xcode 11.3.1 , i am trying to upgrade it but it gives me below error.

Any process to direct migrate without using Xcode 10.1

[image]

Comment: Nope. But the changes from Swift 3 to 5 are not that large. And for many APIs the compiler suggests fixes.